# How do I change the color of my date variable in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a prototype for a chat client. It has no server functions or actual interactivity right now; I'm fairly new to JavaScript/JQuery and I'm only trying to learn how to actually get the text to show up after it's been submitted by a user. With that being said, everything in the code works fine for me as is. Here's what I have in JQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#send').click(function () {
    var text = $('#textField').val();
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    $('#textArea').val($('#textArea').val() + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + text + "\n");
    $('#textField').val('');
});
});
```

I've tried changing the color with variations of date.css('color', '#999999') and such, but the program seems to lose its functionality entirely once I insert that into the code.

Also, how can I insert some white space between the date and the user input? I've tried using &nbsp, but that didn't work.

Comment: _"I've tried changing the color with variations of date.css('color', '#999999') and such, but the program seems to lose its functionality entirely once I insert that into the code."_. That's because `date` is a Date object and not a jQuery object that you can use jQuery's `.css()` method upon.

Comment: Where do you want to insert the coloured date? If in a text field, you need to change the css of the field, not the date object which does not have any css to change

Comment: `$('#textArea').css({color: 'red'});` ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it to the text inside the text area like so:

```
$("#textArea").css({color: 'red'});
```

Js fiddle of hit here http://jsfiddle.net/6uXHL/

Answer (score 0):

You cand find a demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EV5NxYF4g6GvVRYSR1o9?p=preview).
Code (a bit modified to be prettier):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#send').click(function () {
      var textField = $('#textField'),
          text = textField.val(),
          date = new Date(),
          hours = date.getHours(),
          minutes = date.getMinutes(),
          seconds = date.getSeconds(),
          textArea = $('#textArea');

      textArea.val(textArea.val() + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + text + "\n")
              .css({ color: '#999' });

      textField.val('');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, what if I only want to change the color of the date and not the input text?